# Redux. Describe presentational component's lifecycle methods from a container component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Currently I have two components (a container component, and a presentation one). I have some logic that should be implemented in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle methods, in particular I have to dispatch some actions there.

Right now, I'm mapping those action creators in an `mapDispatchToLinkProps` function, and pass them to my presentational component's `props` with a `connect` function, and afterwards, I call them in the `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` methods. Here is how I've implemented it:

**Container component**:

```
const mapDispatchToLinkProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onMount: () => {
      dispatch(loadRooms(ownProps.floor))
    },
    onPropsReception: (nextProps, currentProps) => {
      if (nextProps.floor != currentProps.floor) {
        dispatch(loadRooms(nextProps.floor))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Presentational component:**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToLinkProps)(MapLayer):

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onMount()
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.props.onPropsReception(nextProps, this.props)
}

render() {
// ...
}
```

The thing that I don't like here, is that I lose the context in such a way, and I have to pass `this.props` as the second argument to `onPropsReception` method:

```
this.props.onPropsReception(nextProps, this.props)
```

Is there a way to describe presentational component's lifecycle methods from a container component but keep presentational component's context? Or even better, to override lifecycle methods without any calls within the presentational component?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have the similar problem. I am using react router and redux. I am catching url query parameters(/search?q='foo'&page=1). componentWillUpdate lifecycle method is called when url param changes. I don't know the way to pass lifecycle component using connect method. Or if I how to pass mapStateToProp to React.createClass component.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time to go back here, left the issue unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't add a comment yet,

Why not do the necessary checks in your presentational component & just do a call afterward with the right params ?

ex :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.floor != nextProps.floor) {
    this.props.loadRooms(nextProps.floor);
  }
}
```

ContainerComponent :

```
const mapDispatchToLinkProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onMount: () => {
      dispatch(loadRooms(ownProps.floor))
    },
    loadRooms: (floor) => {
        dispatch(loadRooms(floor));
    }
  }
}
```

What you're asking is doable with some hacks, but it goes against the react & redux philosophy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think so. Making this verification: `if (this.props.floor != nextProps.floor)`  in presentational component I'm implementing a kind of data behaviour, but it should not be done here. 

Now I'm looking towards  `mergeProps` argument in the `connect` method. Dan Abramov provided a very good explanation of how to use it here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/237#issuecomment-168816713

Nevertheless, thanks for your answer!